# Why doesn't this code get the icon image on the title bar of webpage

Tags: html, css, ico

I created the following css file :

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

link {
icon:url(logo_2.png);
}
```

Then in my html file i imported this css file as:

```
<style="text/css">
   @import url("ico_css.css")
</style>
```

I am trying to put up a icon on the webpage. What am i missing ?

Comment: Are you trying to add a "favicon", like something that will show up in the URL bar or browser tab, or add an image to some part of the page itself?

Comment: @program-o-steve: then you should try: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use CSS to add favicons — I don't know where you got that idea.

You do it using:

- An HTML `<link>` element, like this:

  ```html
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo_2.png">
  ```

  This does not involve CSS at all. The `<link>` element does not reference a stylesheet, it references the icon file itself.

  Some browsers don't support PNGs as favicons, so you may have to convert that PNG to an ICO using some online or offline tool to get it to work across browsers.
- If there are too many static pages for you to update, you must convert the PNG into an ICO, place the icon file on the document root of your site and call it `favicon.ico` instead. You won't have to add any `<link>` tags; browsers should discover the icon automatically.

Comment: If there are 200 pages in a website will i have to add this tag on 200 pages ?

Comment: Can't i do this with a CSS file another way ?

Comment: @program-o-steve: Add this line in your header file if you have any.

Comment: have ever heard the word templates?

Comment: @program-o-steve, I can't imagine maintaining a 200 page site without a template or SSI based method.  If you really need to maintain 200 unique pages, you could always do a batch find/replace with a good text editor.

Comment: you mean just keep the favicon.ico file in the root directory and there is no need to place any tag that tells the page about the ico file ?

Comment: @program-o-steve, you can't just rename any graphic file as `favicon.ico`.  It needs to be the proper pixel size (16 x 16) and be converted to an `ico` file type.  You can also embed larger versions (32 x 32 & 48 x 48) inside the `ico` file for the Desktop Shortcut icon (Win only AFAIK).  I posted a link to an online tool that takes care of all that.

Comment: i think with HTML5 there is no need of _shortcut_ in `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="logo_2.png">` but just `<link rel="icon" href="logo_2.png">`

Comment: @ BoltClock i don't see the ico file for mozilla firefox but i do see for google chrome and IE when i place it in the root directory.Why is this ?

Comment: Clear your Firefox cache, maybe.

Comment: @ BoltClock yes it worked. But can you please tell me the reason behind ?

Comment: It's just the browser being finicky with favicons sometimes. Nothing interesting behind it.

Comment: @ BoltClock I didn't understand it.

Comment: @ BoltClock One more thing i just cam across is:IE and Firefox both show the favicon file on the title bar as well as the address bar but Chrome shows the file only on the title bar. Why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

Use this free online tool to automatically convert any image (it retains transparent backgrounds too) and it will output a properly sized `favicon.ico` file and its `link` code.

http://tools.dynamicdrive.com/favicon/